# Uniform Density Function

Tags: distributions, density-function, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, mathematica

As we know the uniform probability density function is

f(x)=1/(b-a)

if i find the density function and area of this uniform distribution between 
(0, 1/2) then it would be

f(x)=1/(1/2-0)
f(x)=2

Now for area i will integrate between these two points which is

f(x) dx = [x^2/2]

```
    = 1/8
```

If above density function (2) and area between points (0,1/2) 1/8 is correct then my interpretation of these calculation in second figure is correct or not?

[image]

If it is correct then the area between (0,1/2) does not seem to me 1/8 graphically , it is showing the same area as between (0,1). Please correct me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total area under any distribution curve will be equal to one. The property holds for the uniform distribution also. The image shows the calculation as well as the graph.[image: Solution]

Comment: i read that integration is used for finding irregular curve area , uniform distro is not irregular shape , it is regular rectangle not like curve

Comment: It is not necessary that integration is used only for the irregular curve. Moreover, the if the area of the rectangle is calculated geometrically then also the area will be 1. Area=Height*width=2*0.5=1

Answer (score 1):

You've integrated f(x)=x not f(x)=2...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76402/discussion-on-answer-by-lukasz-derylo-uniform-density-function).